# Assistance Required for Integrating Search Functionality with Supabase

Tags: supabase, flutterflow, supabase-flutter

I trust this message finds you in good health and high spirits.

I have successfully implemented a "Search Bar" feature in our application, utilizing an API GET Call that interacts with a designated table within our Supabase environment. This development aims to streamline the process for students seeking to identify their respective universities from a comprehensive list of 693 institutions, thereby eliminating the need to navigate through an extensive dropdown list.

Context:
Our database structure in Supabase consists of two primary tables:

**Users:**
This table stores user-specific information, including uid, email, school, among other details.

**School:**
This table catalogs details pertaining to educational institutions, such as id, institution name, code, and country.

**Objective:**
The core functionality I aim to achieve is to allow users to efficiently search and select their university. Upon selection, and by clicking on an "Add" button associated with their choice, the system should capture and record the name, ID, and country of the chosen university into the "Users" table under the user's profile.

**Challenge Encountered:**
While the search module is operational and meets the intended search functionality, I am currently facing difficulties in transmitting the selected university data back to the "Users" table in Supabase.

I am reaching out to solicit any insights, suggestions, or guidance you might have on resolving this issue. Your expertise and advice on how to effectively link the search results with our database to update user information accurately would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you for your attention to this matter. I look forward to your valuable feedback.

Warm regards,

Mike

[image: Search flutter flow]